# What do you use to make javascript more C#-like?

Tags: asp.net, node.js, knockout.js, typescript

I'm starting a new ASP.Net based project using javascript, JQuery etc on the browser.

I'm no expert at javascript and (after years of C# etc) get annoyed with its unstructured, typeless nature, no class hierarcy, everything global, etc. (It may not really be as bad as it sometimes feels!)

I'm aware there's various projects about to make javascript 'better' - things like knockoutjs, typescript, node.js and others - and I'm sure they all have their strengths and weaknesses, and probably one can use combinations of them.

I'm interested to know people's experiences and recommendations for what to use to make the javascript side of ASP.Net programming a little more structured (more like C#?) without too much of a learning curve.

Comment: typescript will have a relatively small learning curve for someone with a strong c# background.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all as javascript syntax is C-like you can write it in such a way that code will look like C. For instance check source code for asp.net ajax library.

Second, there is number of projects which were aimed to help write C# code that is translated to Javascript, that can help you as a starting point. Check http://sharpkit.net/ for that.

But regardless of what you are going to use you absolutely have to understand how javascript works in browser, what is DOM, what facilities window, document and navigator gives you etc etc

I belive that is your main problem, after all, it is really easy to learn how to use namespaces in javascript and bring structure to your code.

Also typescript that you mentioned in comments is really good at making code cleaner and more structured. It also adds classes and inheritance and types and some other cool features that you miss in language again.

So to sum up - you have to learn browser environment, the same way you have to learn .net classes on top of knowing c#-language. You can learn some easy tricks like AMD/require.js/js-namespaces to bring structure to your code, or since you are new and came from .net world - just adopt typescript.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I guess I was meaning using something for the non-GUI bits of javascript, so I wasn't expecting something would replace the need to understand DOM, html controls etc, but to bring more structure to the logic which wires them together. But I understand my question is too subjective for StackOverflow.

Comment: @OliverSeaman typescript brings more than enough features in javascript to do it. start with it.